Ubuntu Installation problem on Packet Tracer on 24.04
I used sudo dpkg -i [program name]
Then I found these error massage,
dpkg: error processing package packettracer (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.4-4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
packettracer

Which command did you use to install it? Please post the full error message by editing your question

Welcome to AskUbuntu! There should be more errors before this that will tell us what exactly failed during the installation like a no such file or directory error, etc. So we need the full error output. Please edit your question and include this additional information.
